# Npgsql and EF error (42703) - column does not exist (One to Many relationship)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, npgsql

The problem persisting occasionaly.  Occurs when I try a insert.
Do anyone have any idea?

> "An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details."
>
> InnerException = ERRO: 42703: coluna"Convenios_Id" da relação "plano" não existe

My properties for relationship:

```
//Convenio Model

[Table(name: "convenio", Schema = "public")]
[Serializable]
public class Convenios
{       
    [Key, Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Planos> ListaPlanos { get; set; }

    /* ... */
}

/* Model Planos */

[Table(name: "plano", Schema = "public")]
[Serializable]
public class Planos
{

    [Key, Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("convenio_id")]
    [Required]
    public int ConvenioId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ConvenioId")]
    public virtual Convenios ConvenioVinculado { get; set; }

    /* ... */

}
```

This is a query generated by `Npgsql/Entity Framework`:

> ERROR:  coluna "Convenios_Id" da relação "plano" não existe no
>   caracter 421 COMMAND:  INSERT INTO
>   "public"."plano"("convenio_id","descricao","codigo","tabela_id","padrao","percpac","percconv","banda_porte","banda_uco","valch","usuario","status","valfilme","codfilme","codigofilm","motivo","limite","mpercconv","mpercpac","fpercpac","fpercconv","autoriza","deparapla","valorauto","autori","ambobriga","descmat","obs","tipotab","valcopart","dtultger","operador_id_ultger","marca","dtultgerini","dtultgerfin","Convenios_Id")
>   VALUES (0,E'Qui et eum soluta sed et expedita',NULL,cast(177 as
>   int8),1,25,75,35,65,cast(30 as
>   numeric),NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,8,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,E'Eos,
>   modi deserunt beatae et eveniet, mollitia omnis voluptate nulla
>   eiusmod labore.',2,61,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,cast(5143 as int8));

I don't have idea about this problem...

Comment: Translating the above error message says **"column "Agreements_Id" of the relation "plane" does not exist"**. Seems pretty obvious to me.

Comment: I do not have this 'Agreements_Id' column in any of my models, why are you requesting this column, could you explain me?

Comment: Sorry, the translator translated too much. Your above error message reads "**coluna "Convenios_Id" da relação "plano" não existe**". Translating it should read "**Column "Convenios_Id" in the table/relation "plano" does not exist**". So to me it looks like your database structure does not match your entity classes.

Comment: I do not have this column in my database and in my entity class either.